# Who was the first American woman to become a millionaire?

Tags: united-states, industry

We hear a lot about millionaires or even billionaires during the Age ov Industry in America. But these were all men. Who was the first American *woman* to become a millionaire?

Comment: I voted to close as trivial because if you put the question into Google, the first result is what the OP cites in self-answer below. Self-answers are intended to capture the fruits of labor of a user, not replicate Google results.

Comment: @called2voyage - Except it may not be correct. Wikipedia just credits her as the first *self-made* female millionaire in the US. Presumably the wife of the first millionaire to die before his spouse is likely to be the answer (depending on will specifics).

Comment: @T.E.D. I suspect, though I may be wrong, that the OP meant self-made millionaire.

Comment: TED those were my thoughts exactly!

Answer (score 4):

[Sarah Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madam_C._J._Walker), a black, was the first American woman, black or white, to become a millionaire.

Orphaned at age six, Walker later became a laundry worker. In 1905, she created a line of cosmetics for black women. At first, she sold her products door to door. They were so popular that Walker’s business expanded until it became a major company.